# Snake game algorithm that doesn't use a grid and the segments can move slower than their dimensions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, coffeescript

I'm trying to do exactly what [this guy is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357440/snake-game-following-segments-non-grid-based) but I *think* he may have less requirements than me because the answers in that post don't seem like they'd work for my game.  Let me inline his algorithm so my question is easier to understand:

> The easiest solution is to loop from tail to head and set the position of the current to the next segment's position, ie: `segment[i].position = segment[i - 1].position`

I think the **key difference** between our requirements is I want to move each piece less than its own width/height on every tick.  For example:

[image]

Pretend these squares are aligned horizontally (I drew it unaligned because I think it makes it easier to see what's going on).  The red `H` is where the head currently is.  The red `T` is where the tail currently is.  The black `H'` is where the head should be next tick.  So the snake is moving right to left.  If I use the algorithm described above, won't the segments overlap or start driving apart?  Let me play it out step by step:

1. Create H'.position
2. T.position = H.position
3. H.position = H'.position

The result of this would become:

[image]

What algorithm can I use to make sure that all the pieces move at the same speed and stay the same distance apart from each other?

---

I'll give my idea, but I'm skeptical of it because my research doesn't show anyone else using this:

Each segment will store it's coordinates and its direction.  EG: `[[50, 50, LEFT], [100, 50, LEFT]]`.  The head is index 0, the tail is index 1.  **The speed at which the snake moves is 10, even though the segments are 50x50**.

Each tick I'll do this:

1. If the mouse was pressed, overwrite the `nextDirection` variable with the direction that was pressed.  Otherwise, `nextDirection` is whatever it was last tick.  In this example, lets assume someone pressed `UP`.
2. Iterate the array and apply the direction to each tick.  EG: `[[40, 50, LEFT], [90, 50, LEFT]]`
3. Shift the directions from head to tail and set the head's new direction to `nextDireciton`.  EG: `[[40, 50, UP], [90, 50, LEFT]]`
4. Repeat every tick.

Does this algorithm seem like it would work?  Part of the reason I'm asking is because it's more complicated than the other guy's algorithm so I feel like I'm doing something wrong.  And also, the more I think about his algorithm, the less it seems like it can work.

---

## Rewording My Problem

Pretend each segment of the snake is a 20x20 pixel rectangle.  Each *tick*, I want the head to move 5 pixels in some direction.  **How do I make sure all the segments stay touching each other?**

@Rafe's description below in a comment is:

> Consider the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake at step `t`, with the leftmost being the tail and the rightmost being the head: `{A, B, C, D, E}`. At step `t+1`, the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake is `{B, C, D, E, F}` where the tail has moved from `A` to `B` and the head has moved from `E` to `F`.

And I don't think this algorithm works because:

> > Yes but if the width of `A = B = C = D = E = F = 20px`.  Shifting `{A, B, C, D, E}` so that it becomes `{B, C, D, E, F}` just added 20px to the right side and removed 20px from the left side.  Doesn't this mean he moved 20px, not 5px?  **I want to move 5px, not 20px**  If you're saying that's accomplished with your suggestion, please explain how.  I don't see it.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when it turns?  If they're moving less than the length of a segment, you're going to have them not line up correctly around a turn.

Comment: @AaronDufour That's fine.  If the algorithm works, they'll straighten out if you go straight for a long enough direction, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you're ignoring the grid but what about making the distance the snake moves forward some number that factors your big block size evenly?

Let's say that you're moving forward only half of the width/height of your block.

Now you can optimize a bit.

- Start a counter, `n`, that runs throughout the game.
- Display the blocks that comprise the snake (`n = 0`).  Let's call this `snake_even`.
- Next move (`n = 1`), create the blocks that comprise the next snake by moving them all forward 1/2 unit.  Let's call this `snake_odd`.
- For all subequent moves, you display either `snake-even` or `snake_odd`, but you can create `snake_even(n+2)` from `snake_even(n)`, or `snake_odd(n+2)` from `snake_odd(n)` just by changing the head to the new position and writing over the tail.
- Whenever the snake eats something, add the length to whichever `snake_xxxx` you're on, and then add the length to the other one.

If you want to move forward only 1/5th of the height, you'd do the same thing, but you'd have five arrays to keep track of instead of two.

**Additional info based on your added example (20x20 px segments moving 5 px each step):**

Take a 4-segment snake moving to the right.  Segment sizes are 20x20 px, and they move 5 px per move.  I'll define the snakes as a list of coordinates `(x, y)`.  I'll mark the head with 'H' and the snake will cycle by moving right in the list, cycling back to the beginning if needed.

```
// n = 0
snake_0 => H(60, 0), (40, 0), (20, 0), (0, 0)

// Snake is moving to the right.
// n = 1 -- construct snake_1 from snake_0 and display that one (n % 4 = 1)
snake_1 => H(65, 0), (45, 0), (25, 0), (5, 0)

// n = 2 -- construct snake_2 from snake_1 and display that one (n % 4 = 2)
snake_2 => H(70, 0), (50, 0), (30, 0), (10, 0)

// n = 3 -- construct snake_3 from snake_2 and display that one (n % 4 = 3)
snake_3 => H(75, 0), (55, 0), (35, 0), (15, 0)

// n = 4 -- Now just move the head, and re-use all but the tail of snake_0
snake_0 => (60, 0), (40, 0), (20, 0), H(80, 0)

// n = 5
snake_1 => (65, 0), (45, 0), (25, 0), H(85, 0)

// n = 6
snake_2 => (70, 0), (50, 0), (30, 0), H(90, 0)

// etc.
```

Now one thing I forgot to take into account was the direction each segment needs to move.  That could be stored right alongside the coordinate.  But I think that part you probably understand already.

Comment: That sounds like a maintenance nightmare to me.  It also feels like the algorithm should be simpler.  And, most importantly, for the purpose of this question I want to assume that there's no grid.

Comment: Well, there is maintenance, but it's not *that* bad. You select the particular snake by `snake_index = n % 2` (or `5`).  All of the head markers into the arrays will be the same.  But when you say "there's no grid" ... well, there *has* to be a grid, unless you're dealing with arbitrary precision.  If performance isn't an issue, then just cycle through all of the pieces and move them however you like.  That's the simplest way.  But I thought you were looking for something more efficient.

Comment: It wasn't until I figured out how to do this on my own that I realized you're giving an algorithm that works.  It was very hard for me to visualize at the time you gave this answer though.  Sorry about that.  Can you do me a favor and look at the algorithm I came up with (I put it as an answer to my own question) and see how you think it compares to yours?  I have a feeling yours might be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I implemented this algorithm:

Basically, I created a `Segment` class.  Each one has a list of pivots.  Whenever the head changes direction, I populate the list of pivots in each of the segments.  Whenever a segment collides with a pivot, it changes to the direction of the segment in front of it.  I then remove that pivot from it's list.

The one downside is you've got to make it so the snake moves by a factor of its own size, otherwise it won't collide with the pivot.

Comment: Maybe you could show a simple example?  (I added one to my answer.  Glad it was helpful BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

In his situation, each segment just moved to where its predecessor was one tick back.

Think of the segments having a solid bar between their centers. If that isn't correct the snake will stretch and bunch up as it moves.

The difference between you and him is that he had longer solid bars so there wasn't overlap.

But if the bar is the length of a movement, each segment will just go where the previous segment was one tick ago. The head is the exception and will move the direction specified by the last mouse click.

Now ... what if the length of the bar is longer than or shorter than the length of a movement.

I think, in that case, you would have to move the head first and then move each segment so it is still the same distance from the previous segment (the one closer to the head).

The hard part is caused by the movement amount not being equal to the distance. When the head changes direction, the 2nd segment has to change both X and Y or it will not be the same distance from the head as it was.

I suggest you:

1. Calculate where the H' is. This is the position of the head after the tick.
2. Calculate the direction from T to H' and
3. move T along that vector until it is the right distance from H.

Useful part ends here ...

**This Part (below here) Isn't Right**

I'll leave it here because what is wrong is that it was moving the tail the same distance the head moved. What it should do is move the tail to where it is the same distance from the head as it was before. ('oneTick' isn't relevant for the tail. We should set the distance between segments at the start and use that length.)

Assume 'oneTick' is the length to move per tick. And 'direction' is UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT

```
if (direction == UP) H'.x = H.x - oneTick;
else if (direction == LEFT) H'.y = H.y - oneTick;
... more elses for the other directions ...

ratio = (H'.x - T.x) / (H'.y - T.y);
dy2 = oneTick * oneTick / (ratio * ratio + 1);
dy = Math.sqrt(dy2);
dx = ratio * dy;

T'.x = T.x + dx; // or minus depending on direction
T'.y = T.y + dy; // or minus ...
```

The direction has to do with the sign of `H'.y - T.y` (for y) and similarly for x.

Comment: "In his situation, each segment just moved to where its predecessor was one tick back."  But look at my first diagram.  H' and H overlap with each other.  If T goes where H is, the segments will be on top of each other.

Comment: They will until you move H according to the direction chosen by the mouse click. Then H will be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm having a ton of trouble visualizing how this will work out.  H' **is** where H will be by the direction chosen.

Comment: Yep. And T' will be at H (not prime), assuming only a head and a tail.

Comment: OK so you're saying T' = H.  As you can see in the diagram, H and H' overlap.  So that means T' and H' would overlap.

Comment: Just like the finished diagram (prime). They overlap at the end just as they did at the beginning. Note that I am assuming that the head moves the same amount in one of the 4 directions with every tick. That's what makes this work.

Comment: Get a box of colored pencils and a piece of graph paper and simulate it. Each tick, you draw dots (for the center of the box) in a different color. Try it.

Comment: They **did not** overlap in the beginning.  Maybe the diagram is bad or you're misunderstanding it: The red boxes are the current state. They don't overlap, they touch.  The black box is where H will end up *next* tick.  If the T ends up where H *was*, now H' and T' will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

so, the snake's head moves freeform, and You check for self-collisions?

The easiest way I see is have a list of positions of the snake head in subsequent frames, then draw the rest of segments at every k-th position from previous head positions. Then at the next frame, You append another head position to the list, and again draw the remaining segments at every k-th position.

If the snake speed is variable, You will have to also vary k, to make the snake not stretch (also possibly interpolate between the head positions). This is simple math.

Comment: What is `k`?   I'm assuming that's where the head was at a tick.  `k` is on the first tick, `k+1` is where it is on the next tick.  That's an interesting way to visualize it.  At first it makes sense to me.  But then I think, "if `k` and `k+1` were rendered at the same time, they'd overlap because the distance between them is less than the size of the segment."  Am I wrong?

Comment: Consider the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake at step t, with the leftmost being the tail and the rightmost being the head: {A, B, C, D, E}.  At step t+1, the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake is {B, C, D, E, F} where the tail has moved from A to B and the head has moved from E to F.  The rest of the set remains the same.  A simple, effective representation of such a set is a circular buffer.

Comment: @tieTYT k is the delta-tick, so You draw the segments where the head was k, 2k, 3k, .... ticks ago.

Answer (score 0):

From the specification, if you consider the *set* of locations occupied by the snake, only the head and tail change at each step.  Therefore you could use a circular buffer to represent the snake and update its position in O(1) time rather than O(n).

Comment: How do you figure only the head and the tail move?  I see that as being true *if* the snake moves on a grid and each "move" is one segment.  But in this case, there is no grid.  A segment may be 20px wide and a move may be 5px.  In which case, it seems to me every piece moves 5px.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Consider the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake at step t, with the leftmost being the tail and the rightmost being the head: {A, B, C, D, E}. At step t+1, the ordered set of locations occupied by the snake is {B, C, D, E, F} where the tail has moved from A to B and the head has moved from E to F. The rest of the set remains the same. A simple, effective representation of such a set is a circular buffer.

Comment: Yes but if the width of `A = B = C = D = E = F = 20px`.  Shifting `{A, B, C, D, E}` so that it becomes `{B, C, D, E, F}` just added 20px to the right side and removed 20px from the left side.  Doesn't this mean he moved 20px, not 5px?  **I want to move 5px, not 20px**  If you're saying that's accomplished with your suggestion, please explain how.  I don't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't that in your requirements.  Umm, if the snake is moving at 5px/frame, won't the segments all be 5px apart, not 20?

Comment: Why would it *have* to be that way?  Think of a worm or a centepede.  It can move at variable speeds.